# Android How do I add some floating button over my custom ListView?

Tags: android, listview, layout, button

I have done my custom ListView, the xml was following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="1px" android:layout_height="1px" android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <ImageView android:id="@+id/img" android:layout_width="26px" android:layout_height="30px" />
      <TextView android:id="@+id/title" android:layout_width="248dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" android:paddingLeft="6dp" android:textSize="20sp" />
      <ImageButton android:id="@+id/cat_icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />
      <ImageButton android:id="@+id/act_icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

'
And code is

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity
{
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.i("MyApp", "ON List create......");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    List<BeanObj> list=...//Do something to fill list
    setListAdapter(new MyListViewAdapter(context, R.layout.item_view, list));
  }

  public class MyListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List<BeanObj>>
  {
    private List<BeanObj> hList=null;
    public MyListViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List hList)
    {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, hList);
      this.hList=hList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
      final BeanObj bean=this.hList.get(position);
      LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
      View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
      // Do something to fill ListView
      return row;
    }
  }
}
```

I did try to add a button on it, but I got each button on each row of list view...

What can I do on xml to add floating button over my custom list view ?
Or, I caeate another xml layout file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="left|top">
  <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogout" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="40dp" android:text="@string/buttonLogout" />
  <View android:layout_width="75dp" android:layout_height="40dp" />
  <Button android:id="@+id/btnList" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="40dp" android:text="@string/buttonList" />
  <Button android:id="@+id/btnSearch" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="40dp" android:text="@string/buttonSearch" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How did I to use it via addHeaderView or addFooterView method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the header and the footer before setting the ListAdapter for the list. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29):

> NOTE: Call this before calling
>   setAdapter. This is so ListView can
>   wrap the supplied cursor with one that
>   will also account for header and
>   footer views.

Also inflating your views in the getView method is not the most optimum way. You need to use a static class for storing the reference to the inflated view. Check out [this](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) talk to correctly set up the views.